# Ionic: How to animate the transition between pages?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework

I’m studying ionic, help me understand how to make the transition between pages as an adrodid. I need to move the pages left and right when switching to another page, they jump up into ionics.

I found several questions and a submitted topic, but they do not work already, because relate to the previous version of Ionic.

What is the easiest way for me to solve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to navigate by swiping pages left and right.

What you want is **slides**.

Check the documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides

(I find the documentation of v3 less confusing than the newest, so check it as well:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/slides/Slides/ )

You can also check **tabs** : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs

It is also possible to combine the above into ***swipeable tabs***, although this is not a build-in functionality in Ionic. Chack this article to get an idea: https://medium.com/@siddhartha.ng/ionic-4-swipeable-tabs-4f3da6e72b71